# Eigen: How to Fix Memory Performance Issues

Tags: c++, memory-management, eigen, tensor, eigen3

I am having some memory performance issues with my Eigen code. For example, using task manager to monitor memory usage I notice that the code uses a lot of memory (more than 10 GBs) which gets worse when increasing the size of Eigen tensors obviously.

I have tried few things to enhance the performance of my code in general, such as the following:

1. Use optimization flags. This ultimately gives me speed up but does not solve the memory performance issues:

```
-ffast-math -fno-math-errno -DNDEBUG -march=native -Ofast
```

2. Avoid passing "large arguments" by value instead by reference, for example:

```
void TensorProduct(Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& Tensor1, Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>& Tensor2, Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& Product){
```

3. Avoid creation of temporary objects since I am using dynamic size matrices. This was achieved by setting up a break point in `check_that_malloc_is_allowed() in Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h` that's triggered when a temporary is created.

I also read somewhere here that maybe I can manage memory through use of `Eigen::Map` instead. However I have used this with Eigen matrix and not Tensor before, so I am wondering if there's a way to implement this so that it would help with my memory performance issues. For example, this is how my Eigen tensors are being initialized in my code:

```
static const int nx = 64;  
static const int ny = 64; 
static const int nz = 64;

Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Product(nx,ny,nz);  
Product.setZero();
Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Tensor1(nx,ny,nz);  
Tensor1.setZero();
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Tensor2(nx,ny,nz); 
Tensor2.setZero();

TensorProduct(Tensor1, Tensor2, Product);
```

Obviously, this is a small part of my code. The full code is much larger and more complex.

NOTE: A realistic working example of my code can be found on my GitHub:
[code](https://github.com/JamieAlM/Eigen_Optimization)

Is this an issue in particular with Eigen library? Is there no way to manage or enhance the memory performance in my ''Eigen'' code? Usually, this may indicate a memory leak when using c++ arrays however, this is not a possibility here so I am not sure how to fix this. Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just scanning the code, `Ecalc_dt3D` returns before calling `fftw_free`. It also takes its function arguments by value. That aside, your main function alone contains (by my count) 142 tensors sized 128x128x128. That alone should account for 2.2-4.5 GiB of memory use.

Comment: @Homer512 Thanks! You make valid point, but even with fixing these small changes I am still getting a usage of > 15 GBs which is a lot more than your estimate 2.2-4.5GBs

Comment: This makes running anything larger than 128x128x128 impossible!

Comment: Other functions such as `EcalcPotSourcek_inertia3D` also allocate similar amounts of tensors. Aside from the one obvious memory leak I don't see any other. You simply request a huge number of large tensors and don't destroy them. If you want to use less memory, restructure your program to require fewer tensors at the same time

Comment: You need to provide a self-contained [mre]. I'm pretty sure that the snippet you provide will not allocate more memory than necessary nor will it leak.